# Phantomjs - Cookies not enabled error

Tags: cookies, phantomjs

I'm pretty new to phantomjs. Just started out with headless automation of the application that I work on. Somehow, the following code seems to work just fine for websites like hotmail,facebook etc but it doesn't work for my application under test. Following is the code that I'm using :-

```
    var page = require("webpage").create();
    page.settings.userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"

    phantom.clearCookies();
    phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;

    var homePage = "https://www.somewebsite.com";
    page.open(homePage, function(status) {
    var url = page.url;
    console.log("Status:  " + status);
    console.log("Loaded:  " + url);

    page.evaluate(function(){
        document.getElementById('myUsername').value='username;
        document.getElementById('myPassword').value='password';
    });

    page.render("before.png");
    page.evaluate(function(){
        document.getElementById('myLoginButton').click();
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        page.render("after.png");
        phantom.exit();
    }, 10000);

  });
```

The error message that I get is "Your browser has been set to block all cookies. Please enable them to log into the website."

Although I have written the statement "phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;" it doesn't seem to enable it. I already tried changing the user agent but with no luck. Am I missing on something ?

Thanks in Advance,
Harshit Kohli

Comment: Some more info wouldnt hurt here. What language/framework is your app written on? This seems like a custom message another developer wrote. Try searching all project files for this message, then post the nearby code.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might face this issue. Setting a user agent for the page should work

```
page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0"
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the command line? I use phantomjs with a PHP driver in Codeception.